# retrofit:2.0.0-beta2 post array of files

Tags: android, retrofit, multipartform-data

I am sending multiple data to server, using retrofit retrofit:2.0.0-beta2. 
Data contains array of Files `ArrayList<File>`.
I am using this code to send apart File:

```
public Call<User> requestUpdateProfile3(String token, File image) {    
RequestBody requestBodyImage = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), image);
            return apiService.updateProfile3(token, requestBodyProfile, requestBodyImage);
```

and this on ApiService

```
@Multipart
    @POST("/shanyraq/profile/update")
    Call<User> updateProfile3(
            @Header(value = "X-AUTH-TOKEN") String toke,
            @Part("1\"; filename=\"1.jpg") RequestBody image);
```

Question is: How Can I Post array of Files using retrofit:2.0.0-beta2??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have uploaded multiple images as like below. Which uploads images with their names.

Service interface:

```
    @Multipart
    @POST(ConstantsWebService.UPLOAD_SERVICES_IMAGE)
    Call<List<String>> uploadImage(
             @Header("Authorization") String token,
             //@Part("file\"; filename=\"902367000083-1.jpg") RequestBody mapFileAndName); //for sending only one image
             @PartMap() Map<String,RequestBody> mapFileAndName); //for sending multiple images
```

And request:

```
    HashMap<String,RequestBody> map=new HashMap<>(listOfNames.size());
    RequestBody file=null;
    File f=null;

    for(int i=0,size=listOfNames.size(); i<size;i++){
        try {
            f = new File(context.getCacheDir(), listOfNames.get(i)+".jpg");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Bitmap bitmap = getImageFromDatabase(listOfNames.get(i));
            if(bitmap!=null){
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, fos);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            }else{
                view.showErrorView("imageNotFound"); //todo
                return;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            view.showErrorView("imageNotFound || file not created"); //todo
            return;
        }

        file=RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), f);
        map.put("file\"; filename=\""+listOfNames.get(i)+".jpg",file);
        file=null;
        f = null;
    }

    serviceOperation.uploadImage(token,map).enqueue(){..}
```

So you change return type, Header name, image name.

Comment: can I send array of file in one RequestBody?

Comment: RequestBody class has methods named `create` which all take File or MediaType object as argument. So i think you can't store array inside RequestBody, but you can send array of RequestBody to webservice

Comment: How do you specity the name/value. If I want to send it to the server under "images[]" how can i do that?

Comment: @Sree : Any answers ?

Comment: @Code_Life no. Please post here if you do find the answer

Comment: does anyone have the server side php code for this ?

Answer (score 1):

I would be happy and delighted if this could help you as well.

Server API contract :
Input Type : Multipart-from data

Data to be send in body against key called "**images**"

```
@POST("feeds")
Call<> createFeeds(@Body RequestBody file);


 MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder();
    builder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
    builder.addFormDataPart("content", textContent);

    for(String filePath : imagePathList){
        File file = new File(filePath);
        builder.addFormDataPart("images", file.getName(),
                RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file));
    }

    MultipartBody requestBody = builder.build();
    Call<SocialCreateFeedResponse> call = mSocialClient.createFeeds( requestBody);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Interface structure:
    @Multipart
    @POST("user_edit_profile_save")
    Call<EditProfileDto> saveEditProfile(@Part("first_name") RequestBody first_name, 
                                         @Part MultipartBody.Part profile_picture);


    Calling:
RequestBody requestBodyUserId = RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), "5");
MultipartBody.Part body = null;
            if (path != null && path.length() > 0) {
                file = new File(path);
                isImageSet = true;
                requestBodyPicture = RequestBody.create(
                        MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
                body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("profile_picture", file.getName(), requestBodyPicture);

            } else {
                requestBodyPicture = RequestBody.create(
                        MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), "");
            }
```

Comment: please give some description before writing your code-review